# Python-Jira package

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am new to `Jira-Python` module. I am using below snippet to connect to my `jira` server.

```
try:
    print "Connecting to JIRA: %s" % jira_server
    jira_options = {'server': jira_server, 'verify':False}
    jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                basic_auth=(jira_user, 
                            jira_password))
    return jira
except Exception,e:
    # jira_options = {'server': jira_server, 'verify':False}
    # time.sleep(60)
    jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                basic_auth=(jira_user, 
                            jira_password))
    print "Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e
    sys.exit()
```

Sometimes above codes works fine. But most of the times it fails with below error:

```
 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my_jira_server_name', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D48450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

Can any one help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is not related to your network?

Comment: Thanks. But is there anyway to check whether it is related to network issues?

Comment: put the code in a try / catch block and have another go (after a delay) if max retries is seen.  Also I notice the error is coming from urllib3, which has configurable retries see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#retry

Comment: thanks. But not working. I have tried like this.                                       try:
        jira_options = {'server': jira_server, 'verify':False}
        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                    basic_auth=(jira_user, 
                                jira_password))
        return jira
    except Exception,e:
        time.sleep(60)
        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                    basic_auth=(jira_user, 
                                jira_password))
        print "Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e
        sys.exit()

Comment: I have tried to change the retry count also. But not connecting to server.
..\urllib3\poolmanager.py 

        retries = 10#kw.get('retries')        
        if not isinstance(retries, Retry):            
        retries = Retry.from_int(retries, redirect=redirect)